# Proper join of the given tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am trying to display the content based on 5 tables in my relational database.Scenario: I sell services based on the phone lines. Tables involved: orders (holding info about the client and the contract), contract (connecting the order with my employee who will look after it), employee, number (holding info about the number itself, connecting to 1 or more extensions) and the extensions table. 
TABLES

```
CONTRACT      ORDERS    EMPLOYEE    NUMBER       EXTENSIONS
--------    ----------- --------    ------       ----------
contract_id order_id    employee_id phone_number extension_id
employee_id location    name        contract_id  phone_number   
order_id    description ...     ...     ...
...
```

My problem is that data gets populated in several different steps so if I just connect all the tables together using the WHERE clause no data gets displayed. (Please see the following query)

```
SELECT  orders.location as service_location, contract.employee_id as id, 
        employee.name as name, number.phone_number as phone, 
        extension.extension_number as extension, contract.order_id AS order_id
FROM  orders,
      contract,
      employee,
      number,
      extensions
WHERE orders.client_id = 1
  and orders.order_id = contract.order_id 
  AND contract.employee_id = employee.employee_id
  AND contract.contract_id = number.contract_id
  AND number.phone_number = extensions.phone_number
```

I assume that I could use the above code if the phone_number (tbl number) and extensions (tbl extensions) already existed in the db (as I get the intended outcome before I use number and extension tables). In my scenario if they don't exist I would need the rest of the table populated and these two columns to return the empty fields until they get populated through the php interface. Would JOIN fix my problem? How to adapt it to my scenario?

expected outcome:

```
service_location| id       |  name | order_id | phone  | extension 
--------------  | ---------| ------| -------- |  ----- | ---------
```

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, add sample table data and the expected result (as formatted text, not images.) Take a look at [mcve] first.

Comment: @jarlh thx. I'll do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must, first use the explicit JOIN sintax, and then use the on clause to make the correct join.
I have used LEFT JOIN, but you can use other joins if those are your needs.

```
SELECT  a.location as service_location, b.employee_id as id, 
        c.name as name, d.phone_number as phone, 
        e.extension_number as extension, b.order_id AS order_id
FROM  orders a
    LEFT JOIN contract b on a.order_id = a.order_id 
    LEFT JOIN employee c on a.employee_id = c.employee_id
    LEFT JOIN `number` d on a.contract_id = d.contract_id
    LEFT JOIN extensions e on d.phone_number = e.phone_number
WHERE a.client_id = 1
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I've changed the table aliases in the JOIN clause to create the connections and it works as intended. Thanks again. You saved my day

Comment: @nacho . . . Learn to use meaningful table aliases.  Arbitrary letters are a maintenance nightmare.